# google calendar sync poblems

Tags: android, ios, google-calendar, microsoft-surface-pro

I've got an ipohne 6s and an android note 5. They both have Google calendar installed. I am having the worst time getting events created on the mobile devices to show up on Google Calendar when I look at it on my Surface. I've been scouring the internet, but can't seem to get this issue resolved. I'm also having problem syncing events between the ios and android device. Have 3 gmail accounts that are all set to share with each other. Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Did you read the android, google and ios tags you included?

Comment: Duly noted, but if you read my post, it is related to a computer issue. In so far as it is not syncing to my Surface.